# ReactJS react-router-dom - Components not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new here but a long time reader of StackOverflow content!

I am new to React and have a simple question about Multi-Pages App.

I did start to work on a website for a friend, I started with a one-pager but finally I did realize that I will need more then only one page.  I installed react-router-dom and tried to set it up, the website doesn't return any errors, but only the *SideBarMenu* component is showing up !

the content of Home is not showing on */* , same for the rest on */audio*, */video*, */images*... And the weirdest part of it, if I write as URL for example some random thing like */asiomaos9j*, it still show a blank website with the *SideBarMenu* without even crashing...

Anyone know why all my component on *Home* are not showing?  Or even on */images* the *js* file only contains a *div* with a *H1* inside and this *H1* not showing either...  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with this !

I did import as follow:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then here is my App.js :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Routes />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

My Routes.js :

```
export default function Routes() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/audio" component={AudioPlayerApp}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/video" component={VideoPlayerApp}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/images" component={ImagesApp}></Route>
        </Switch>
  


        <SideBarMenu pageWrapId={"page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"app"} />
        
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

Finally as example, here is my Home.js

```
function Home(){
    return(

        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />

            <Services />
            <ServicesContent />

            <Media />
            <MediaContent />

            <Studio />
            <StudioContent />

            <Partenaires />
            <PartenairesContent />

            <Contact />
            <ContactContent />

            <Footer />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Here as asked, SideBarMenu.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu';
import './components_css/SideBarMenu.css';

export default props =>{
    return(
        <Menu {...props}>
            <a className="menu-item" href="#">
                <span>+</span>Accueil
            </a>
            <a className="menu-item" href="#services_link">
                <span>+</span>Services
            </a>
            <a className="menu-item" href="#media_link">
                <span>+</span>Médias
            </a>
            <a className="menu-item" href="#studio_link">
                <span>+</span>Studio
            </a>
            <a className="menu-item" href="#contact_link">
                <span>+</span>Contact
            </a>
        </Menu>
    );
};
```

These are links inside the Home page for the moment.

Comment: can you show the SideBarMenu component?

Comment: I added the code of SideBarMenu component on the post !

Comment: You should use react-router `Link` component instead of anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the exact out of the home route and place it at the end of all others

Comment: Into the switch, placing this :   ```<Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route> ``` at the bottom?  It didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you read the part where I said remove exact from home ?

Comment: Hello Ernesto, thank you so much for your help, it work!  Sorry English is my third language and I didn't understand well the first time !  Have a wonderful day !

Comment: Also. Here is the docs it comes with a whole bunch of examples  https://reactrouter.com/web

Comment: i placed it at the end of all others but still not working